# I have confusion on relay and graphql resolve method

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

Apologies if this is a stupid question. this is the code for relay/graphql pagination that's confusing me:

```
const GraphQLTodo = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Todo',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Todo'),
    text: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.text,
    },
    complete: {
      type: GraphQLBoolean,
      resolve: (obj) => obj.complete,
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});

/* When pagination is needed, make a connection */ 
const {
  connectionType: TodosConnection,
  edgeType: GraphQLTodoEdge,
} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Todo',
  nodeType: GraphQLTodo,
});

const GraphQLUser = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('User'),
    todos: {
      type: TodosConnection,
      args: {
        status: {
          type: GraphQLString,
          defaultValue: 'any',
        },
        ...connectionArgs,
      },
      resolve: (obj, {status, ...args}) =>
        connectionFromArray(getTodos(status), args),
    },
    totalCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: () => getTodos().length,
    },
    completedCount: {
      type: GraphQLInt,
      resolve: () => getTodos('completed').length,
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
const Root = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Root',
  fields: {
    viewer: {
      type: GraphQLUser,
      resolve: () => getViewer(),
    },
    node: nodeField,
  },
});
```

You can see that on the GraphQLTodo field, it has text and complete fields with resolve function passed an obj parameter, how is obj passed there? is it from GraphQLUser resolve? I've read on docs that source(in this case obj) - The object resolved from the field on the parent type. is it not from the root query? how is obj here created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Connection

Here is where (some of) the magic happens:

```
const {
  connectionType: TodosConnection,
  edgeType: GraphQLTodoEdge,
} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Todo',
  nodeType: GraphQLTodo,
});
```

You have now told GraphQL that a `TodosConnection` is going to be made up of `GraphQLTodo` nodes. Now, let's take a look at where the objects are actually fetched for the connection in your `GraphQLUser` object, which is on the `todos` field:

```
todos: {
  type: TodosConnection,
  args: {
    status: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      defaultValue: 'any',
    },
    ...connectionArgs,
  },
  resolve: (obj, {status, ...args}) =>
    connectionFromArray(getTodos(status), args),
},
```

So where does the object come from? The key part here is the `getTodos` function, which is responsible for actually getting an array of the objects from your data source. Since this field is a `TodosConnection` and we've already specified in the connection definitions that the nodes are `GraphQLTodo`s, GraphQL knows that the `text` and `complete` fields are resolved by getting (in this case) identically named fields on the objects that have been returned. In other words, the returned object is passed to the `resolve` method on each field.

## Querying the Root

You have two fields exposed on `Root`: `viewer` and `node`. Ignoring `node` for a moment, you have just one way to actually query todos. Since `viewer` is of type `GraphQLUser`, and `GraphQLUser` has that `todos` field, they can be fetched only as a subfield of `viewer`, like this:

```
{
  viewer {
    todos(first: 10) {
      edges {
        # each node is a Todo item
        node {
          text
          complete
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## Mystery of the Node

But what about that `node` field? Relay wants to be able to fetch any object using a top-level query, i.e. on your `Root` field, when given a unique `globalId`, which is just a base64 encoding of the type name and the id, so `Todo:1` is encoded to `VG9kbzox`. This is set up in the `nodeDefinitions` (which you haven't included here, but probably have). In those definitions, the `globalId` is parsed back into the `type` (`Todo`) and `id` (`1`), and once again you then tell it how to fetch the correct object from your data source. It might look something like:

```
const { nodeInterface, nodeField } = nodeDefinitions(
  (globalId) => {
    const { type, id } = fromGlobalId(globalId);
    if (type === 'Todo') {
      return getTodo(id)
    } else if (type === 'User') {
      return getUser(id)
    }
...
```

Because you're implementing the `nodeInterface` in both your `GraphQLTodo` and `GraphQLUser` types, Relay will be able query for either of them from the `Root`'s `node` field.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be sharing your answer on our community page(facebook) I hope there's a way we can connect with you @Eric Streeper